# Cómo añadir una nueva fila en Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Estoy trabando en un programa que filtre datos de un excel, no he podido avanzar por el siguiente inconveniente. La siguiente tabla es de referencia de una reporte de facturas del mes, necesito que se sumen los valores de la misma referencia y se añadan a una nueva fila

| Referencia | Valor | Descuento |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FVE474 | 100000 | 0 |
| FVE474 | 71400 | 0 |
| FVE475 | 96000 | 96000 |
| FVE475 | 68544 | 0 |
| FVE476 | 205000 | 0 |
| FVE476 | 71400 | 0 |
| FVE477 | 57600 | 0 |
| FVE478 | 54000 | 0 |

De la siguiente manera, adicional que pueda eliminar la columna Descuento y que los valores mayores se añadan en la columna valor y que conserve la referencia.

| Referencia | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| FVE474 | 100000 |
| FVE474 | 71400 |
| FVE474 | **171400** |
| FVE475 | 96000 |
| FVE475 | 68544 |
| FVE475 | **164544** |
| FVE475 | **96000** |
| FVE476 | 205000 |
| FVE476 | 71400 |
| FVE476 | **276400** |
| FVE477 | 57600 |
| FVE478 | 54000 |

Añado el código del programa

```
def abrir_archivo():

    archivo = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir ='/', 
                                            title='Selecione archivo', 
                                            filetype=(('xlsx files', '*.xlsx*'),('All files', '*.*')))
    indica['text'] = archivo



def Limpiar():
    tabla.delete(*tabla.get_children())

def Procesar():
    datos_obtenidos = indica['text']
    try:
        archivoexcel = r'{}'.format(datos_obtenidos)
        

        df = pd.read_excel(archivoexcel)

    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror('Informacion', 'Formato incorrecto')
        return None

    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showerror('Informacion', 'El archivo esta \n malogrado')
        return None

    Limpiar()

    # se convierten los valor en 0 a null
    # se excluyen las columnas innecesarias
    # por ultimo, se eliminan las columnas que todos sus valores estan null 
    nan_value = float("NaN")
    df.replace(0, nan_value, inplace=True)
    df.drop(['RazonSocial', 'IdProducto', 'CodigoProducto', 'DVTercero', 'Unidades', 'ValorUnitario','TarifaIVA', 'TarifaConsumo','TarifaDescuento', 'TarifaRetefuente', 'TarifaReteIVA', 'TarifaReteICA'], 'columns', inplace=True)
    df.dropna(how = 'all', axis='columns',inplace=True)

    # df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['FechaFactura','Referencia', 'NombreProducto','Tercero', 'IdentificacionTercero', 'ValorTotal', 'ValorReteFuente'], value_name='ValorTotal')

    tabla['column'] = list(df.columns)
    tabla['show'] = "headings"  #encabezado
    

    for columna in tabla['column']:
        tabla.heading(columna, text= columna)
    

    df_fila = df.to_numpy().tolist()
    for fila in df_fila:
        tabla.insert('', 'end', values =fila)
```

Comment: Y que has intentado? Coloca el codigo de tu avance para que la comunidad te ayude. Visita el [tour] para que sepas como funciona  SOes y de igual manera aprendas [ask].

Comment: @GmrYael He intentado con esta linea de codigo pero no hace lo que necesito

`df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['Referencia', 'Valor'], value_name='Descuento')`

Comment: @GmrYael realice una edición a la pregunta, adjunte el código

Comment: @GmrYael **actualización:**
Logre obtener la suma con `dataframe.groupby`

Comment: @NESS1996 si encontraste la solución, ponla ABAJO en el campo Tu Respuesta. COmparte con otros; puedes incluso marcarla como aceptada y podrás recibir votos positivos

Comment: @Alfabravo cuando termine completamente se las comparto, solo llevo la primera parte, por así decirlo

Comment: Por favor, aclara qué parte de lo que dices que quieres lograr, no funciona o falla.

Comment: la linea que comparti en el primer comentario no hace lo que requiero, me di cuenta que para lograrlo debo primero realizar otros procesos, primero (es lo que ya hice) es sumar los valores ['Valor'] en la tabla, por referencias, esto lo tengo en un nuevo dataframe, lo siguiente que debo hacer es combinar estos dos dataframe